# Возможность сравнивать значение первого индекса со вторым

Tags: java

есть код с двумя циклами первый перебирает первый элемент цикла
второи цикл перебирает 2 элемент цикла
и между ними сравниваются

```
for (String s1 : list) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String s2 : list) {
            if (s1.equals (s2)) {
                count++;
                result.put (s1, count);
            }
        }
```

я хотел бы это сделать в один цикле fori чтобы элемент индекса 0 сравнивать с индексом элемента 1 как можно это реализовать и при этом не упасть из цикла?

Comment: Что-то вы слишком мудрено все описали. Может стоит попробовать как-то более понятно описать вопрос, а то я лично вижу только кашу из названий. В любом случае стоит посмотреть на метод `contains( )` который есть как у HashSet ([HashSet: contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object))), так и у ArrayList ([ArrayList: contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)))

Comment: Что Вам нужно сравнить?  Длину s1 и s2? Их содержимое? По коду Вы сравниваете именно содержимое, а говорите про индексы. Каким образом у Вас организован массив строк?

Comment: сравнивать элементы короче говоря  найти одинаковые слова в списке то есть строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Sckoriy");
list.add("Sckoriy");
list.add("Sergey");

for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() - 1 ; i++){
   if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1)){
      //Strings are same! 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае сравнить текущий элемент массива со следующим можно так

```
   int arr []= new int [5];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        int j = i+1;
          if (arr[i]==arr[j]){

           // Пишем что нужно сделать
          if (j>arr.length){
         break; 
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хм,а что ты будешь делать если у тебя будет i = 4 ? Получать 6 элемент массива,если у тебя только их 5?

Comment: @Sckoriy упс.. Исправлюсь

Comment: А вообще,этот 0-индекс,это ужас.Я так из-за него напрягаюсь,мол нужно считать с 0.

Comment: @Sckoriy Привыкайте, это не самое страшное в программирование))

Comment: значит такой вариант не возможен или как

Comment: Кажется,что снова не правильно.Все равно будет выход.Нужно просто сделать - i < arr.length - 1 , и тогда мы последний элемент не будем сравнивать с пустотою.

Comment: насчет == не лучше ли equals все таки строки сравниваем